# make site fit exactly width and height of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, height, width

I need to have my site fit exactly to the user's browser, this means any browser and any size of monitor. i need to have no scroll bars both vertical and horizontal

I want to do this in javascript/jquery

I have this code:

```
screen.width
screen.height
```

i also tried jquery :

```
$(window).height()
$(window).width()
```

also had scroll bars.

Is this the only way?? cuz when i used it on my site, i had scroll bars both vertical and horizontal. it was to big.

Can any one please help?

Comment: Consider taking a hint from all the massive sites on the internet, including stackoverflow.com, just choose a set width, have it centered.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.

No way you'd be able to fit your content to all display resolutions (think ipads, smartphones [each with different resolutions], 30" monitors, etc).

by the way:

```
// both of these on their own do nothing.
$(window).height() // just returns to you the viewport height
$(window).width() // just returns to you the viewport width
```

Comment: forget all cases, regular PC monitors are fine, any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
body {height: 100%; width: 100%;}

div#page_container {height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

No need for JS/jQuery, just wrap all your content inside `<div id="page_container"></div>`

It also resizes with people resizing browser windows.

Comment: that wouldn't work unless you set `overflow: hidden` on the page container. But even then, if you did it, you'd be missing some or most of the content depending on your resolution and viewing device

Comment: You just have to work with percentage for the nested elements width. This is anyways not viable for image-heavy content, where you are facing fixed sizes, but for a fluid layout, consisting of divs, you can make that work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7nM4E/1/ See here for a live example, you would have to stick using percentage values. And you would not be able to support all screen sizes, unless you would make EVERY content-container you use scrollable, which is not exactly eye-catching

Comment: @semyazas what if the text/content inside of page_container div FORCES the its height to extend past the viewport size (Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/6UZnJ/)? Here's that same example but with `overflow: hidden` (where you'll be missing some of the content):  http://jsfiddle.net/6UZnJ/1/. What do you propose for those cases? Don't forget that as the window is resized to a smaller width, the content increases the height even more.

Comment: I propose to not use that kind of layout, but since the OP asked, he got an answer on his question. YES, it is possible, YES it has its quirks. But if he's developing for, say, a very special audience, or is able to keep his content below several minimum requirements, no need for him to not go for it. That doesn't mean i consider that a "good" approach. I just show possibilities

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Phil.  There is going to be no way to determain the resolution of the users screen.  That is going to be a user problem.  I have always built my web sites at 1024 x 768 resolution for that reason.  Sometime even lower depending on the content, and the target audience(sites that target older people who probably have a low resolution setting so they can read their screen).This way, I know that my stuff will fit.  Most people now a days, with monitors the size that they are, do not go much below that.

I found this code here at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287171 that might help you though.  This will adjust the screens height and width based on the users screen resolution.

Also remember that some JavaScript will not work in certain browsers.  I have run into this problem with pop-ups when it came to changing screen size, scrollbars ect...